# Development webpack building taking lot of time

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, jhipster, npm-start

I'm working on an Angular 4 project (created through JHipster), which takes a lot of time to build the project on startup as well as rebuilding after making minor change to any of the file.

It takes minimum of 10 minutes to build a appox. 4500 sub-modules.

[image: Screenshot of webpack build]

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const path = require('path');

const utils = require('./utils.js');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = 'development';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig({
  env: ENV
}), {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './target/www',
    proxy: [{
      context: [
        '/uaa',
        /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
        '/api',
        '/management',
        '/swagger-resources',
        '/v2/api-docs',
        '/h2-console',
        '/auth'
      ],
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
      secure: false
    }],
    watchOptions: {
      ignored: /node_modules/
    }
  },
  entry: {
    polyfills: './src/main/webapp/app/polyfills',
    global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
    main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main'
  },
  output: {
    path: utils.root('target/www'),
    filename: 'app/[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'app/[id].chunk.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.ts$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loaders: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: ['node_modules', new RegExp('reflect-metadata\\' + path.sep + 'Reflect\\.ts')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          'angular2-template-loader',
          'awesome-typescript-loader'
        ],
        exclude: ['node_modules/generator-jhipster']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
      },
      {
        test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
        exclude: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/
      },
      {
        test: /(vendor\.css|global\.css)/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 9000,
      proxy: {
        target: 'http://localhost:9060'
      }
    }, {
      reload: false
    }),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new writeFilePlugin(),
    new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
      utils.root('src/test'),
    ]),
    new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
      title: 'JHipster',
      contentImage: path.join(__dirname, 'logo-jhipster.png')
    })
  ]
});
```

I tried googling and find a solution but to no avail.

Comment: Mate, I recommend you to instal latest versions of your packages and angular version. There are too much differences about build times.

Comment: @shadowman_93, upgrading angular as of now is not a feasible solution as it is a huge application.

Comment: have you tried to increase node memory for webpack in package.json?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou, I did try that.

Comment: Can you try it on a mac or linux machine? Usually windows does not handle a lot of small files very well.